# Define TypeScript type using a function that tests the value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Exactly as it says in the title. Example would be defining a type `Integer` such that `x` only qualifies as `Integer` if `isInteger(x)` returns `true`.

Comment: Are you just look for [type predicate functions?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) If not, please elaborate.

Comment: You _could_ use branding to do something with type branding like this: https://tsplay.dev/Nngg6m. If that is what you mean I could write that answer up for you, but I'm not sure that's really a good idea, or what you want.

Comment: @AlexWayne Are type predicate functions a way to create a type defined by a value `x` satisfying `typeof x === "number" && x % 1 === 0`? If so, then maybe those are what I have in mind.

Comment: How is the "type branding" in your example any different than plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't do this type of thing. Typescript facilitates a layer of *design-time* tooling that serves as guard-rails to prevent the authoring of code that is not likely to work. What you're asking for is a *runtime* check.

Comment: TypeScript's documentation mentioned some runtime checks.

Comment: What's stopping `typeof x === "number" && x % 1 === 0` from being used as a compile-time check when there can be complicated checks based on properties?

Comment: At compile-time you don't know the *value* of x. That's what's stopping it. The check you want could be in a utility function -- at runtiime a value is provided as an argument to the function -- but it can't be part of a TS type.

Comment: So how can types defined on the basis of possessed properties be implemented as compile-time checks? Not knowing the value of `x` at compile-time is a lot like not knowing the properties of `x` at compile-time. Furthermore, if not knowing the value of `x` at compile-time poses a problem for what I asked, then how can TypeScript implement types like `type Bit = 0 | 1`? That's identical to a hypothetical test-based type defined as `function isBit (x) { return x === 0 || x === 1; }`!

Comment: @Melab `0 | 1` is a numeric literal constraint -- you can specify a precise list of literal values so you can force any reference to only pass in one of those literal values. But the set of integers is an (effectively) infinite range of values, so you cannot specify them all literally in this way. You could constrain to any integer, say, from 0 to 100 with `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 ...` etc, but this is an obviously impractical way to obtain a general integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript cannot differentiate an integer from a float. You have `number` which is any floating point number, and you have finite unions of number literals like `1 | 2 | 3`. That's all you get.

---

However, one way to emulate this is with [branded types](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+branded+types&sxsrf=ALiCzsZDv6y8YNDzqRTx08Gvja1ESsiRCQ%3A1661276222655&ei=PhAFY_vCJ6Dg0PEP5rOD2Ac&oq=typescript+branded+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzoHCAAQRxCwAzoECAAQQzoGCAAQHhAWSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUMcGWKMOYJQUaAFwAHgAgAE7iAG7ApIBATaYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz). Branding lets you stamp a bit of metadata on a type that make it different that than the type receiving the stamp. This lets you write a type predicate that verifies somethings at runtime, and if it passes then is considered to bear that brand.

For example:

```
const integerBrand = Symbol('integerBrand')
type Integer = number & { [integerBrand]: true }

function isInteger(x: number): x is Integer {
    return x === Math.floor(x)
}
```

Here we first create a symbol to use a key for the brand. We use a symbol because that means that key will be globally unique and guaranteed not to clash with any type that this brand will be added to.

Then we create a type called `Integer` which is an intersection of `number` and an object with the symbol as it's only property. This branding object never exists at runtime, it just to make typescript acknowledge this type as a special number.

Lastly, we create a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) called `isInteger` that tests a number and casts it to `Integer` if the test was successful.

Now we can create a function that only accepts `Integer` arguments:

```
function addInts(a: Integer, b: Integer): Integer {
    return (a + b) as Integer
}
```

And some numbers to play with:

```
// maybe integers, maybe not.
const a = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 3.1459
const b = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : 1.6180
```

Now if you pass these `number`s to that, you get a type error:

```
addInts(a, b) // type error
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Integer'.
```

But if you check them with `isInteger` first it will work.

```
if (isInteger(a) && isInteger(b)) {
    addInts(a, b) // fine
}
```

The downside of this approach is that the brand must be applied by your functions exclusively, which can be a verbose pain.

---

You could also have a `createInt` function to make `Integer`s for you.

```
function createInt(x: number): Integer {
  if (isInteger(x)) return x
  throw new Error("x is not an integer value")
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-viIDleN7tQwmUiUexfjKciqadXbf4YGHA2AkL8IE8C7wgA)

Comment: I looked at the transpiled output and I don't get how this is any different than having `isInteger` inside a function and throwing an error if it returns `false` in normal JavaScript.